# c# Web Service referencing c# project referencing DLL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dllimport

Alright, so maybe this is inadvisable, but I'm writing a Web Service for an existing application. I'm trying to use the C# Library we wrote for the project, and that C# Library uses functions from a dll that is not acreated from a .NET project. I know the DLL isn't a problem, because the actual application (A windows form application) that uses the c# Library has no problem performing operations that use this dll, but my web service always crashes when the dll methods are called. The exception is:

"Unable to load DLL 'foo.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}  System.Exception {System.DllNotFoundException}

A sample of the import from the c# Library:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll")]
protected static extern void DllFunction(string param1, int param2, int param3);
```

I tried adding foo.dll to the Bin directory of my project, but this didn't work. I feel like I must be missing something really obvious. Any suggestions? I've read some funky things about DLLs and web services and tried a couple of fixes such as http://sites.google.com/site/tosapage/programming/asp-net#dll but they didn't work.

Comment: Does the DLL need to be registered with regsvr32? Are you missing registry keys specific to the DLL? Is your web service on the same box as your form application?

Comment: Did you saw this post? http://forums.asp.net/p/1033370/1422579.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would run the winforms exe with [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).  You might be getting that error for a dell that the dll you are calling needs.

Comment: That was my problem. I was just asking my supervisor and he informed me of the other DLLs that I was missing. Thank you!